# Adding RICHFACES to existing JSF2 project

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I'm trying add richfaces to my JSF 2 project using this [jboss guide](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_0_X/Developer_Guide/en-US/html/chap-Developer_Guide-Getting_started_with_RichFaces.html#step-Developer_Guide-Creating_a_project-Reference_the_tag_libraries). I've did what they say in point 2.6, but after restart my tomcat server, HTTP Status 404 is reported.

Have I missed something??

**UPDATE:** 
When I add richfaces-components-ui-4.0.0.Final.jar and richfaces-core-impl-4.0.0.Final.jar, and restart the tomcat server, it reports:

```
INFO: Unsanitized stacktrace from failed start...
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: 
Source Document: jar:file:/D:/WORKSPACE/BC/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/PORTAL/WEB-INF/lib/richfaces-core-impl-4.0.0.Final.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml
Cause: Unable to create a new instance of 'org.richfaces.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl': java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.createInstance(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:293)
....

13.5.2011 8:41:52 com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
SEVERE: Critical error during deployment: 
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! com.google.common.base.Function
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:379)
....

13.5.2011 8:41:52 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! com.google.common.base.Function
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:292)
....
13.5.2011 8:41:52 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
13.5.2011 8:41:52 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/PORTAL] startup failed due to previous errors
13.5.2011 8:41:52 com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextDestroyed
SEVERE: Unexpected exception when attempting to tear down the Mojarra runtime
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory
at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:894)
....
```

And now I'm not sure which libraries are neccessary for JSF2 and which for RICHFACES..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to `readme.txt` of RichFaces 4 the following JARs are required:

> In addition to the RichFaces jars, a number of dependencies are required in order to properly configure the framework.
>
> a.  `sac-1.3`, `cssparser-0.9.5` - required for components CSS work.
>
> b.  `google-guava-r08` - core runtime dependency.
>
> c.  `annotations.jar`  - from org.richfaces.cdk.
>
> - It's optional and only needs to be added if RichFaces components will be created/accessed dynamically in your apps actions/listeners.
>
> d.  `validation-api.jar` and any implementation like hibernate-validators.jar
>
> - It's optional and should be added if you using Client or Graph 
>             Validation. Should be added only if it's not provided by a 
>             server (Java EE 6 servers).

Your exception suggests that you don't have the Google Guava library.