# richfaces + eclipse ee + tomcat 7

Tags: jsf, tomcat, configuration, richfaces

am having a problem configuring tomcat with richfaces. I copied the:

```
richfaces-components-ui-4.2.2.Final.jar
richfaces-components-api-4.2.2.Final.jar
richfaces-core-api-4.2.2.Final.jar
richfaces-core-impl-4.2.2.Final.jar
```

jars into tomcat's \lib and restarted my server. The definition of my xhtml page looks like this:

```
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
     xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
     xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
     xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
     xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
     xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
```

But eclipse generates a warning which says

```
NSL missing: CANNOT_FIND_FACELET_TAGLIB in : org.eclipse.jst.jsf.core.validation.internal.facelet.messages
```

Is there any other thing I need to configure? I skimmed a lot of tutorials but almost all uses JBoss. Is there a way to configure richfaces with my eclipse and tomcat?

---

Edited

When I add the jars as external jars, and add the dependencies too, it does not crash the site,though in the console it produces a this:

```
Jun 10, 2012 2:15:55 PM org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.config.MyfacesConfig getBooleanInitParameter
INFO: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.PRETTY_HTML' found, using default value true
Jun 10, 2012 2:15:55 PM org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.config.MyfacesConfig getBooleanInitParameter
INFO: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.ALLOW_JAVASCRIPT' found, using default value true
Jun 10, 2012 2:15:55 PM org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.config.MyfacesConfig getBooleanInitParameter
INFO: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.RENDER_CLEAR_JAVASCRIPT_FOR_BUTTON' found, using default value false
Jun 10, 2012 2:15:55 PM org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.config.MyfacesConfig getBooleanInitParameter
INFO: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.RENDER_HIDDEN_FIELDS_FOR_LINK_PARAMS' found, using default value false
Jun 10, 2012 2:15:55 PM org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.config.MyfacesConfig getBooleanInitParameter
INFO: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.SAVE_FORM_SUBMIT_LINK_IE' found, using default value false
Jun 10, 2012 2:15:55 PM org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.config.MyfacesConfig getBooleanInitParameter
INFO: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.READONLY_AS_DISABLED_FOR_SELECTS' found, using default value true
Jun 10, 2012 2:15:55 PM org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.config.MyfacesConfig getBooleanInitParameter
INFO: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.RENDER_VIEWSTATE_ID' found, using default value true
Jun 10, 2012 2:15:55 PM org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.config.MyfacesConfig getBooleanInitParameter
INFO: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.STRICT_XHTML_LINKS' found, using default value true
Jun 10, 2012 2:15:55 PM org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.config.MyfacesConfig getBooleanInitParameter
INFO: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.RENDER_FORM_SUBMIT_SCRIPT_INLINE' found, using default value false
Jun 10, 2012 2:15:55 PM org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.config.MyfacesConfig getLongInitParameter
INFO: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.CONFIG_REFRESH_PERIOD' found, using default value 2
Jun 10, 2012 2:15:55 PM org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.config.MyfacesConfig getBooleanInitParameter
INFO: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.VIEWSTATE_JAVASCRIPT' found, using default value false
Jun 10, 2012 2:15:55 PM org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.config.MyfacesConfig getStringInitParameter
INFO: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.REFRESH_TRANSIENT_BUILD_ON_PSS' found, using default value auto
Jun 10, 2012 2:15:55 PM org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.config.MyfacesConfig getBooleanInitParameter
INFO: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.REFRESH_TRANSIENT_BUILD_ON_PSS_PRESERVE_STATE' found, using default value false
Jun 10, 2012 2:15:55 PM org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.config.MyfacesConfig getBooleanInitParameter
INFO: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.VALIDATE_XML' found, using default value false
Jun 10, 2012 2:15:55 PM org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.config.MyfacesConfig getBooleanInitParameter
INFO: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.WRAP_SCRIPT_CONTENT_WITH_XML_COMMENT_TAG' found, using default value true
Jun 10, 2012 2:15:55 PM org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.config.MyfacesConfig createAndInitializeMyFacesConfig
INFO: Tomahawk jar not available. Autoscrolling, DetectJavascript, AddResourceClass and CheckExtensionsFilter are disabled now.
Jun 10, 2012 2:15:55 PM org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator feedStandardConfig
INFO: Reading standard config META-INF/standard-faces-config.xml
Jun 10, 2012 2:15:56 PM org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator getWebAppConfig
INFO: Reading config /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml
Jun 10, 2012 2:15:56 PM org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator startLib
INFO: Starting up MyFaces-package : myfaces-api in version : 2.0.2 from path : file:/D:/Programming/Eclipse%20Workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/OnTheRun/WEB-INF/lib/myfaces-api-2.0.2.jar
Jun 10, 2012 2:15:56 PM org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator startLib
INFO: Starting up MyFaces-package : myfaces-impl in version : 2.0.2 from path : file:/D:/Programming/Eclipse%20Workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/OnTheRun/WEB-INF/lib/myfaces-impl-2.0.2.jar
Jun 10, 2012 2:15:56 PM org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator startLib
INFO: MyFaces-package : tomahawk not found.
Jun 10, 2012 2:15:56 PM org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator startLib
INFO: MyFaces-package : tomahawk12 not found.
Jun 10, 2012 2:15:56 PM org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator startLib
INFO: MyFaces-package : tomahawk-sandbox not found.
Jun 10, 2012 2:15:56 PM org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator startLib
INFO: MyFaces-package : tomahawk-sandbox12 not found.
Jun 10, 2012 2:15:56 PM org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator startLib
INFO: MyFaces-package : tomahawk-sandbox15 not found.
Jun 10, 2012 2:15:56 PM org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator startLib
INFO: MyFaces-package : myfaces-orchestra-core not found.
Jun 10, 2012 2:15:56 PM org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator startLib
INFO: MyFaces-package : myfaces-orchestra-core12 not found.
Jun 10, 2012 2:15:56 PM org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator startLib
INFO: MyFaces-package : trinidad-api not found.
Jun 10, 2012 2:15:56 PM org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator startLib
INFO: MyFaces-package : trinidad-impl not found.
Jun 10, 2012 2:15:56 PM org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator startLib
INFO: MyFaces-package : tobago not found.
Jun 10, 2012 2:15:56 PM org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator startLib
INFO: MyFaces-package : commons-el not found.
Jun 10, 2012 2:15:56 PM org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator startLib
INFO: MyFaces-package : jsp-api not found.
Jun 10, 2012 2:15:56 PM org.apache.myfaces.util.ExternalSpecifications isBeanValidationAvailable
INFO: MyFaces Bean Validation support disabled
Jun 10, 2012 2:15:56 PM org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator handleSerialFactory
INFO: Serialization provider : class org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.util.serial.DefaultSerialFactory
Jun 10, 2012 2:15:56 PM org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.DefaultLifecycleProviderFactory getLifecycleProvider
INFO: Using LifecycleProvider java.lang.String
Jun 10, 2012 2:15:56 PM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer initFaces
INFO: ServletContext 'D:\Programming\Eclipse Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\OnTheRun\' initialized.
Jun 10, 2012 2:15:56 PM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer initFaces
```

Which I assume is because some libraries are missing

---

UPDATE

Here are my config files:

```
<faces-config
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">
<application>
    <resource-bundle>
        <base-name>on.run.messages</base-name>
        <var>msgs</var>
    </resource-bundle>
</application>




<navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/login.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>secret</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/restricted/transactions.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect/>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>



</faces-config>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>OnTheRun</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<filter>
        <filter-name>AuthFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>on.run.AuthFilter</filter-class>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>AuthFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/restricted/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
</web-app>
```

I also tried tomahawk lib, but I removed it and cleaned the project. I tried this example to test [richface](http://www.mastertheboss.com/web-interfaces/271-richfaces-calendar-example.html) but there is nothing displayed.

The console message still remains valid, even though I don't have any reference to tomahawk neither I have it in my buildpath and the project and server is clean. I also tried to add to the buildpath myfaces-impl.jar, does not help. The same console messages come up.

Comment: how looks your `web.xml` and `faces.config.xml`? it appears you are using `myfaces`, so have you myfaces libraries (`myfaces-impl.jar`) in your lib directory?

Comment: you'd better try to create a completely new richfaces project using the guide which we talked about, and after that compare the running hello world project with the old one. I still don't know if you have `myfaces-impl/api.jar` in your lib folder

Comment: i do have it in my folder. Eclipse put it there, it created a JSF2.0 Apache Myfaces Core library. I will try out with a new project.

Comment: https://community.jboss.org/thread/156461 .. similar situation here

Comment: but I don't know nothing about myfaces and its xml configuration, you can always try to replace it by mojarra jsf..

Comment: I made a new project with default configs and the same warnings appear in the console.

Comment: See my updated answer, it must help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *But eclipse generates a warning which says*
>
> ```
> NSL missing: CANNOT_FIND_FACELET_TAGLIB in : org.eclipse.jst.jsf.core.validation.internal.facelet.messages
> ```

That's because you placed the RichFaces libraries in Tomcat instead of in webapp itself. Those libraries are supposed to be placed in webapp's own `/WEB-INF/lib`. Otherwise you need to add the RichFaces libraries to the server-supplied libraries in Eclipse project buildpath settings. Eclipse namely doesn't expect that you modify the default libraries of Tomcat.

---

> *When I add the jars as external jars, and add the dependencies too, it does not crash the site,though in the console it produces a this:*

Those are just INFO messages, not WARNING messages. This is specific to MyFaces and those are just to inform the developer/serveradmin what actions MyFaces has taken as to setting some applicationwide parameters. Just ignore them. Only once you get a WARNING, SEVERE, ERROR or FATAL, then you may start worrying. You do not necessarily *need* Tomahawk.

Answer (score 1):

Folowing dependencies [are required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987933/adding-richfaces-to-existing-jsf2-project):

- `sac-1.3.jar`,
- `cssparser-0.9.5.jar` - for CSS styling.
- `guava-r09.jar` - core runtime dependency.

And of course `javax.faces.jar` for JSF (or myfaces alternative), take a look [here](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_2_X/Developer_Guide/en-US/html/chap-Developer_Guide-Getting_started_with_RichFaces.html)

**UPDATE:**

And @BalusC have [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546219/nls-missing-message-cannot-find-facelet-taglib) these steps:

- Close/reopen project.
- Rightclick project > *Validate*.
- *Project > Clean*... and clean selected project.
- Restart Eclipse.

**UPDATE 2:**

I've prepared a **working** initial (Dynamic Web) project based on mojarra JSF 2.1, you can [download it here](http://www.sendspace.com/file/7it774). Place [this libraries](http://resize.like.cz/images/62_168_44_170_11-06-12-07-06-27_1339391187libs.jpg) to its WEB-INF\lib folder, start it on tomcat7 server:

```
http://localhost:8080/TEST/
```

Comment: it turns out I had to remove the richfaces libraries. I will try again

Comment: Ok. What happens is this: if I copy the richfaces-ui and -api it kills my css styling. If I copy all four jars my project stops working. If I copy the dependencies nothing happens. The project stays the same, producing a 404 error.
This site [How To...](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToAddRichFaces4xToProjectsNotBasedOnMaven) gave me the same steps, but I think something is not compatible here

Comment: did you tried the cleaning of the project suggested by BalusC? do you have javax.faces.jar in your lib folder?

Comment: what about to try previous version of RF? I'm using v4.1.0. Just for test

Comment: Thank you, I have right now a lot of work, but I will let you know how I managed.